# Why I keep getting this error " Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script" even I get desired output

Tags: python, lua, redis

I trying to execute this lua script i get proper output too. But i keep getting **Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script**

```
def new_get_following(self, start, count, user_id=0):
        script = """
        local envs = redis.call('zrevrange',KEYS[1],ARGV[3],ARGV[4]);
        redis.call('sadd',ARGV[1],unpack(envs));
        local favs = redis.call('sinter',ARGV[2],ARGV[1]);
        local acts= redis.call('mget',unpack(envs));
        redis.call('del',ARGV[1]);
        return {favs,envs,acts}
        """
        count = int(start) + int(count) - 1
        print count
        fav_key = self.fav_key + ":" + str(user_id)
        following_stream_key = self.following_stream_key + ":" + str(user_id)
        tmp_key = int(time.time())
        return self.exectute(script, args=[tmp_key, fav_key, start, count], keys=[following_stream_key])
```

Comment: Use the MONITOR command (from redis-cli) to understand what is exactly sent to Redis by your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is just a typo and has already been corrected but:

`self.exectute` shouldn't it be `self.execute`?

Answer (score 1):

In the code last line is causing error.

```
local envs = redis.call('zrevrange',KEYS[1],ARGV[3],ARGV[4]);
local acts= redis.call('mget',unpack(envs));
```

As if envs is empty table then second line:

```
local acts= redis.call('mget',unpack(envs));
```

becomes this:

```
local acts= redis.call('mget',unpack());
```

so lua keeps throwing error. For avoid this error we can use `redis.pacall` which gives Response error object which can be checked in output can handle error. So final code should be

```
def new_get_following(self, start, count, user_id=0):
        script = """
        local envs = redis.call('zrevrange',KEYS[1],ARGV[3],ARGV[4]);
        redis.call('sadd',ARGV[1],unpack(envs));
        local favs = redis.call('sinter',ARGV[2],ARGV[1]);
        local acts= redis.pcall('mget',unpack(envs));
        redis.call('del',ARGV[1]);
        return {favs,envs,acts}
        """
        count = int(start) + int(count) - 1
        print count
        fav_key = self.fav_key + ":" + str(user_id)
        following_stream_key = self.following_stream_key + ":" + str(user_id)
        tmp_key = int(time.time())
        return self.exectute(script, args=[tmp_key, fav_key, start, count], keys=[following_stream_key])
```

Comment: That seems wrong. `acts` would be true or false, whether the pcall succeeded or not. So you are not getting the results from mget anywhere. Why don't you test envs length first with #envs and if > 0 then you do the mget thing ?